# Complex structs in Rust, when following ownership rules

Tags: programming-languages

### Background

I recently started learning [the rust programming language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/).

Suppose you want to create some complex `struct`, for example - a graph.

I can see two possible implementations of this:

The first, uses `Rc` to create multiple ownership (so that the nodes own directly other nodes). The struct, might look similar to this:

```rust
struct Node {
   neighbors: Vec<Rc<Node>>,
}
```

However, using this implementation, one cannot "hold" the entire graph at once.

The second implementation will have the ownership be held by a wrapper graph object, and the nodes will only have references to the other nodes instead of actually owning them:

```rust
struct Node {
    neighbors: Vec<&Node>,
}

struct Graph {
    nodes: Vec<Node>,
}
```

In this implementation, we do have acess to the entire graph at once (through the `Graph` struct). However, now when deleting nodes in the graph we have to do an operation that takes $O(n)$ time (removing the node from the `nodes` list).

In my opinion, the second implementation is better - since it is cleaner and cannot cause memory leaks. However I wouldn't like to have that extra $O(n)$ cost when deleting nodes (as opposed to $O(deg(v))$ in the first implementation).

---

### Question

I'm having trouble understanding how the borrowing rules (without using `unsafe`) can still allow me to create such an implementation. Does anyone know a feature of Rust that can help in this case? Thanks!

---

Honestly, I don't know if this fits this site or the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) site, so please tell me in the comments if I need to move this question there :)